# Where can I change the wording of the Reset Password email FreeMember sends?

Tags: email, freemember, forgot-password

The question says it all. Here's the why:

When FreeMember sends a password reset email, the text is as follows:

> [screen_name],
>
> To reset your password, please go to the following page:
>
> [http://www.example.com/member/reset-password/[hash]](http://www.example.com/member/reset-password/%5Bhash%5D)
>
> Then log in with your username: [username]
>
> If you do not wish to reset your password, ignore this message. It will
> expire in 24 hours.

The problem is that I'm using an email+pwd login method, not username+pwd, so I'd like to alter the email to say "email" instead of "username".

Another issue is the fact that the email shows the member's "username" instead of "email". In most cases members registered via FreeMember's system, so their email and username will be the same. However, for members created prior to implementing FreeMember, or members registered via other methods (EE backend, etc), their username is probably *not* the same as their email, making the Reset Password email's wording misleading.

Both issues can be fixed by changing the wording and tags of the FreeMember email, so... where can that be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the forgot_password template in `EE Control Panel > Design > Message Pages > Email Notifications > Forgotten Password Instructions`. You can change the username variable and text to email.

Now you will have to add the email variable. In `system > third_party > freemember > libraries > freemember_lib.php` after line 276 add

```
$email_vars[0]['email'] = $member->email;
```

Comment: Ahh, of course. Didn't realize FreeMember could piggy-back on EE's native email templates like that, thanks!